# Create current version of BQ table from history

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I have a BigQuery table which gets updated with rows by a batch job every one hour. The job appends rows that are modified in an external system and would be in the format below.

| Supplier_ID | Supplier_Name | Supplier_Contact | Last_Modified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC | 03 483 394 | 2023-05-01 12:34:56 |
| 124 | ABD | 02 848 939 | 2023-05-01 12:34:56 |
| 123 | ABC | 03 483 345 | 2023-05-02 10:45:05 |
| 124 | ABD | 02 848 837 | 2023-05-02 10:45:05 |
| 123 | ABC | 03 478 102 | 2023-05-08 11:09:15 |

I want to create a current version of the table like below which shows the latest record of all the Suppliers with only one record per Supplier_ID.

| Supplier_ID | Supplier_Name | Supplier_Contact | Last_Modified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC | 03 478 102 | 2023-05-08 11:09:15 |
| 124 | ABD | 02 848 837 | 2023-05-02 10:45:05 |

The size if the table would be in millions.
What would be the best way to achieve this? I don't want to create a view since the size of the table would keep growing and the systems which would consume this new table needs a faster response time.

Option 1:
Run another batch job and create the table having the max of the timestamp for each Supplier_ID. But the drawback would be creating the entire table even if only one record got updated.

Option 2:
Creating materialized views. I haven't worked on this till now. But if this is better then I would explore this.

Looking for your suggestions on the best way.

Comment: You can consider using materialized views for your requirement. For more information you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-manage#:~:text=You%20can%20alter%20a%20materialized,MATERIALIZED%20VIEW%20and%20SET%20OPTIONS%20.).

Comment: Did the above document help you?